# Will databases with a large set of records affect read speed? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization, where-clause

Our company has recently been signed up with a franchise to provide their customers our POS (cash register) application, leading us to have about 3-5 new sign ups every week. Currently we create a duplicate copy of the application's database for every new customer, but I can tell already that this approach could end up crushing us. We were thinking maybe it'd be best to use one database for all clinics identified by some form of client id on each table.

Now we got into a bit of a debate on that topic: one coworker was saying having a large table with 50,000 will make things too slow, and we'd have to optimize the entire application. Another coworker was saying MySQL was designed to handle large databases, and as long as you specify the client id in each queries WHERE clause then you'll receive a subset of the data, with practically no change in speed.

Will selecting a subset of data from a large table (100,000+) have any significant speed difference from selecting the same number of rows from a smaller table?

Also, any recommendations on which way to go for the database design would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, 100k records is a relatively small table; if your database server is good enough performance impact will be minimal. As with everything you'll have to test first. However, you have to bear in mind that your clients may not want to have the data merged with that of their competitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data size *would* affect performance, but with proper indexing, lookups in 50-100k records should not be any problem. A production database I work with (~1.25 million records) takes negligible time (less than 0.005 sec) to look up a record by primary key.

Still it depends on your actual use; you might end up having to optimize some queries and add some extra indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split 'em up into several smaller tables instead of one long and large table. If designed and indexed right, it should be quicker in the long run.

Comment: What reason do you have for your statement?

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the speed of select (read) queries, you could add an index to the columns that you query by.

For example, if you query by some sort of clinic identifier, you could put an index on that column. This will help the database traverse the data and find the records that match your criteria without looking at every record in the database (this is where slowdowns occur). If, in the future, you query by a different criteria (let's say a date), you could put an index on that column as well.

Keep in mind that adding indexes will increase runtime performance but will increase the physical disk size required to store the data.

Comment: I think the index was implied by the question.

Comment: Situational cues in the question influenced the level of detail in my response.